# Convert "System.String" to the type "System.Security.SecureString" failed

Tags: powershell

I want to decode a password from the credential manager with `ConvertFrom-SecureString`:

```
$creds = Get-StoredCredential -Target PIN
$secureString = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $secureString  -AsPlainText
```

However, I get an error:
The SecureString parameter cannot be bound. The value
"XXXX" of type "System.String" cannot be converted to type "System.Security.SecureString".
What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ```Password``` property is a ```[string]``` (you can see this with ```$cred | gm``` -> ```Password       Property   string Password {get;set;}```). Try ```$creds.GetNetworkCredential().SecurePassword``` instead.

Comment: Or, more simply: `$secureString = $creds.Password`